# How can I calculate the PI controller gain valuesfrom a transfer function?

Tags: control-theory

I am doing a project where I am using a synchronous bidirectional buck-boost converter too handle to powerflow between a battery and a dc bus. I have spend some time figuring out and understanding how to find the transfer function of my converter with state space modelling and have think I finally understand the whole process. My next step is to use that transfer function to calculate some gain values for the PI controller which i want to control converter with.

I have found my transfer function with state space modelling by following the example in a guide from texas instruments [Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjDtsbi6tf7AhXCSfEDHUGJChkQFnoECBcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fpdf%2Fsprabx5&usg=AOvVaw0KQ3FzKjrkKYy94kBCAuRq) (at the bottom of the guide they have attached a matlab script to copy in order to get the transfer function yourself). I have some other values for the components than texas, but taking initiative in the result from the guide is a good start, I think.

In the guide the following transfer function fro the converter is:

```
   1.699e06 s^5 + 6.499e09 s^4 + 1.813e13 s^3 + 2e16 s^2 + 1.032e18 s + 1.351e19
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 s^6 + 4395 s^5 + 1.894e07 s^4 + 3.143e10 s^3 + 5.071e13 s^2 + 2.9e15 s + 4.221e16
```

I think my biggest problem is that i don't know where to start. I know these definitions for PI controller, but I just can't see how it is connected.

omegaK = 1/ti

Gs = Kp *(1+1/ti) (PI controller)

Sorry for maybe not being too specific, I am not the strongest in control theory and really hope someone have time to give me an answer or show how to do it.

Best regards
Mads

```
clear all;
clc;
s = tf('s');
% Values below is from an example made by texas instruments
% Input Voltage
Vp= 200;
% Input resistance
Rp=2.75*10^-3*200;
% Input capacitance
ci=1*10^-3;
% Input capacitance ESR
Rci=74*10^-3;
% DCR of the inductor
Rl=9.6*10^-3;
% Inductance
l=130*10^-6;
% Output Capacitance
co=15*10^-3;
% Output Capacitance ESR
Rco=5*10^-3;
% Output Load
Io=80;
% Duty cycle
D=0.5;
% The matrice for solving of inductor current transfer function
C = [0 0 1];
Dm = 0;
% This is the expresisons for the state vector values and they are
% verified.
iL=Io/(1-D);
vci=Vp-Io*Rp/(1-D);
vco=(Vp/(1-D))-((Io*(Rp+Rl+D*(1-D)*Rco))/(1-D)^2);

% determining the state and input matrices for the converter in ON and OFF
A1 = [0 0 0; 0 -1/(ci*(Rp+Rci)) -Rp/(ci*(Rp+Rci)); 0 Rp/(l*(Rp+Rci)) (-(Rl*Rp+Rl*Rci+Rci*Rp))/(l*(Rp+Rci))];
B1 = [-1/co 0; 0 1/(ci*(Rp+Rci)); 0 Rci/(l*(Rp+Rci))];
A2 = [0 0 1/co; 0 -1/(ci*(Rp+Rci)) -Rp/(ci*(Rp+Rci)); -1/l Rp/(l*(Rp+Rci)) (-(Rl*Rp+Rl*Rci+Rci*Rp+Rp*Rco+Rco*Rci))/(l*(Rp+Rci))];
B2 = [-1/co 0; 0 1/(ci*(Rp+Rci)); Rco/l Rci/(l*(Rp+Rci))];
% Determining the state and input vectors
X = [vco; vci; iL];
U = [Io; Vp];
A_avg = A1*D+A2*(1-D);
B_avg = B1*D+B2*(1-D);

% Finding the transfer function
% (sI-A)
SIminusA = s*eye(3)-A_avg;
% (sI-A)^-1
inv_SIminusA = inv(SIminusA);
% (A1-A2)X+(B1-B2)U
A1minusA2XPlusB1minusB2U = (A1-A2)*X+(B1-B2)*U;
% Inductor current to duty cycle Trasnfer Function
% C*((sI-A)^-1*((A1-A2)X+(B1-B2)U))
y_IL = C*(inv_SIminusA*A1minusA2XPlusB1minusB2U)

y_IL1 = minreal(y_IL)
% pole-zero-gain model
zpk(y_IL1)
% Display poles
pole(y_IL1)
% Display zeros
zero(y_IL1)

% Bodeplot af TF
figure;
hold on;
bode(y_IL1)
grid on;
title('Bidirectional Buck-Boost converter transfer functions');
legend('TF');
```

Comment: Hello Mads and welcome! How to tune the controller depends on what properties you want the closed-loop system to have, for instance, do you want to have high bandwidth, low overshoot from a reference step, good disturbance rejection, robustness w.r.t system uncertainty or variation etc.?

Comment: Hey. This is quite applied and specific questions, you may try your luck on the Subreddit r/ControlTheory and the associated Discord server.

Comment: Hi @FredrikBagge! It has come to my attention that it is not possible to directly calculate the Kp and Ki of a PI controller for a higher order system (3rd or more). Since my system is a 3rd order system when the poles and zeros are cancelled out. One guy in mathworks comment on my similar question there that the best would probably be to brute force some combinations of different values for Kp and Ki and find the one step response i find most satisfactory.

Comment: @FredrikBagge the link to my question is here https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1868258-how-can-i-calculate-the-pi-controller-gains-from-my-plant-transfer-function?s_tid=srchtitle